# Adb install failed : INSTALL_FAILED_BLOCKED_CROSS_DOWN

Tags: installation, adb, failed-installation

trynig to install an apk app using Adb prompt cmd :
C:\adb\platform-tools>  .\adb install "C:\adb\platform-tools\myapp.apk"

Performing Streamed Install

and than it says :
adb: failed to install C:\adb\platform-tools\myapp.apk: Failure **[INSTALL_FAILED_BLOCKED_CROSS_DOWN: INSTALL_FAILED_BLOCKED_CROSS_DOWN]**

PS : i used the adb cmd because the app won't install in normal methode (incompatible device)
my device is samsung A20 .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an incorrectly signed application.

I cleared the project and generated the signed application again and the problem was gone